# How does android generate 'current.txt' it's api description file?

Tags: java, android, android-source, android-make

I'm investigating how to generate a file exactly like current.txt for my own java source (I want it to be compatible with other code I use to parse the android current.txt, so I want the format to be the same).

The android repo has a file called current.txt, as you can see here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/api/

Which lists out a description of every class that Android has.

All I've been able to find is that it looks like there's an intermediate step which uses a javadoc 'doclet' called doclava to output an xml file (project found here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/doclava/). There's no where I can find in the android codebase that converts that XML file to the plain txt format that current.txt has.

Comment: Any question or so?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a proper full 'make' before 'make update-api' will have
any effect.  All that the update-api target does is a "cp" of the API
description that resulted from the last full build to the current.xml
reference location.

Source -https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-platform/Y3xSWM-qc8c/-Pve9p3rcpQJ